# extending USQL with C#: which are parallelised?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

As described in [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/extending-u-sql-expressions-with-user-code),

> there are several ways how C# code can be used to extend U-SQL
> expressions
>
> - Inline C# Expressions
> - User-Defined Aggregators
> - User-Defined Functions
> - User-Defined Operators

Which one are able to run in parallel in Azure Data Lake Analytics (ADLA)?

Answer (score 2):

You can see the degree of parallelism of your query in the execution plan and this depends on the way data will be processed. For example, if you use any of the expressions you mentioned to treat the value of a selected column, you can parallelize 100% of your data, because it can split data processing by rows.